# Vertical scrolling in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, browser, scrollbar, scroll

I have a silverlight application that is set to use 100% browser height.

As I dynamically add controls to a canvas (which can be dragged around), I would like the expand the canvas vertically.

Ideally show the browser scrollbar so the user can move up or down, if that can't be done, use the scrollbar control. I would also need to handle the user changing the size of the browser. Any suggestions on how to do this ?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your Canvas inside of a ScrollViewer as follows:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Canvas>
        ...
    </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Jim McCurdy
Face to Face Software and YinYangMoney